# How can I get a url from a universal link?

Tags: ios, swift

I usually use the delegate method below when I clicking the universal link to open the app from an inactive/background state; however, it isn't called from a non-running/dead state so I can't use the NSUserActivity object, which provides me the Universal link url I need.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
                   restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
```

If you are aware of another solution, delegate method, or anything else that may help me get the url please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: What is your goal exactly? Are you trying to continue user flow after he installs your app?

Comment: Actually, yes. When the user installs the app & opens the app it goes into an active state, if the user then clicks the home button it's in a background state, and if user double clicks on home button and swipes the app to kill it it goes to a non-running state. the delegate method restorationHandler that returns the NSUserActivity object doesn't get called if the app is in a non-running state; therefore I can't receive the NSUserActivity object which provides me the url I'm looking for which is the url of the universal link.

Answer (score 0):

Through this delegate method I receive the universal link in app delegate. Please try it. It may helps you.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
}
```

Comment: Hi Sanjukta, are you sure you are using universal link and not deep link? I believe you are using deep links. Unless I'm mistaken, the delegate method you provided is only called when using deep links.